# Can't debug in Visual Studio when using local IIS WITH hostname

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-7.5, .net-4.5, visual-studio-debugging

I have a solution that contains multiple projects, two of which are web applications that have their own separate domains. I have this published successfully to my dev/production environment fine and now would like to mirror these settings across to my local machine for better testing.

I have configured the project to run under Local IIS and enter the required Url for both projects and hit debug, I'm then presented with the following error:

```
Unable to start debugging on the web server. 
Invalid access to memory location.
```

Interestingly if I change my IIS configuration and remove the hostname and change the port to 81/82 (and reflect these changes in VS) then I can successfully start debugging my application.

This is more of an irritation than anything else as I can work without the custom hostnames and configure the rest of IIS perfectly, however this does get in the way of logging into both systems simultaneously.

I tried a number of recommended fixes such as:

- Ensured app pool is running
- Restarted Visual Studio
- Restarted computer
- Run VS as Administrator

Comment: I periodically get this.  If I then try debugging again, it usually seems to work the second time.